# How to create an entity with several dates in a single form with EasyAdmin

Tags: symfony, easyadmin, symfony5

I am trying to develop my first symfony web-app and I have decided to use the bundle EasyAdmin.

In this web-app, I would like to define the following model : an `Event` with several dates.

In order to create this, I have create 2 entities with the help of the symfony console : `Event` and `EventDate`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventRepository")
 */
class Event
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EventDate", mappedBy="event", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $dates;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dates = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|EventDate[]
     */
    public function getDates(): Collection
    {
        return $this->dates;
    }

    public function addDate(EventDate $date): self
    {
        if (!$this->dates->contains($date)) {
            $this->dates[] = $date;
            $date->setEvent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDate(EventDate $date): self
    {
        if ($this->dates->contains($date)) {
            $this->dates->removeElement($date);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($date->getEvent() === $this) {
                $date->setEvent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString(): String
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventDateRepository")
 */
class EventDate
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", inversedBy="dates")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $event;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEvent(): ?Event
    {
        return $this->event;
    }

    public function setEvent(?Event $event): self
    {
        $this->event = $event;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

In order to be user-friendly, I would like to "customize" the form of an `Event` in order to allow the user to create in the same form the event and its dates.

In order to do this, I have define the `Event` entity's form like that:

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Event:
      class: App\Entity\Event
      form:
        fields:
          - {property: 'name'}
          - {property: 'dates', type: 'collection'}
```

The render of the collection is right because I can add or remove a date:

[image]

But As you can see, the field that represent the `EventDate` is an edit text. I think it's because the field represent the `EventDate` class and not only the `date` attribute.

The aim is to have the date selector that I have if I add a new `EventDate` in EasyAdmin:

[image]

So the question is: How to custom EasyAdmin in order to add an `Event` and its dates in a single form?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do it.

I need to modify my yaml EasyAdmin file in order to introduce an `entry_type`:

```
easy_admin:
  entities:
    Event:
      class: App\Entity\Event
      form:
        fields:
          - {property: 'name'}
          - {property: 'dates', type: 'collection', type_options: {entry_type: 'App\Form\EventDateForm', by_reference: false}}
```

Then, I have to create the `EventDateForm` class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class EventDateForm extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('date');
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\EventDate'
        ));
    }

}
```

I also need to update the `$date` attribut of my `Event` entity like this:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\EventDate", mappedBy="event", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
private $dates;
```

The render is not very beautiful but it works:

[image]